# Is the Google Analytics API containsSampledData field reliable?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are running the Google Analytics free version and I'm seeing some inconsistent results regarding data sampling. I have tried my requests in Google Analytics Query Explorer, the GA Sheets add-on, and within the GA interface.

Basically, I am comparing results from a complete date range against the sum of results for that date range broken into smaller chunks (to reduce/remove the chance of sampling occurring). Metrics are sessions, transactions, and revenue. I have a session-level dynamic segment applied: sessions::condition::!ga:landingPagePath=@/thanks

As you may expect, the results from the single request are different (counts are lower) than those from summing the multiple smaller requests. For example, sessions are 45,311 vs. 51,596 and income is further apart. This implies that sampling is being used for the larger request. The trouble is that the API response explicitly says that sampling is not used in any case, i.e. "Contains Sampled Data" equals "No", even for the full date range within which our property should be exceeding the 500,000 session threshold for sampling to kick in.

I'm almost certain that the results from summing smaller date ranges are correct, as these are pretty close to what we see in our CMS analytics.

Can anyone explain the mechanics behind this? Is GA doing some sort of behind-the-scenes sampling to produce this inconsistency?

Thanks, 
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like sampling. Check all your sources to see if they contain sampling and make sure you have Sampling Level Set to "HIGHER_PRECISION".

1) **Google Sheets Google Analytics Add-On** in cell B6 of the data for each query check to see if it says "Yes: for "Contains Sampled Data"

2) **Google Analytics Query Explorer** in the header below your profile name check to see if it says "Contains Sampled Data: Yes"

You are on the right track in breaking your query down into smaller chunks with smaller date ranges to avoid sampling. Here is a post on how to [Avoid Google Analytics Sampling using Python](http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/)

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the helpful answer and tip on using Python. However, in this case the specific problem I'm seeing is that "contains sampled data" seems to be getting set to "no" when the data is in fact still sampled (I verified this by comparing to CMS data)